# info on partitioning in survival trees

Tags: r, distribution, prediction, survival-analysis, rpart

I'm hoping to use survival trees for my dataset, where so far I mainly used proportional hazards models. I'm interested in obtaining quantiles of the survival function. I'm struggling a bit to understand how survival trees partition the data and what the actual output of the model is.

in rpart's manual i couldn't find much than this:
[image]

[image]

My guess is that `rpart` tries to do is either fit Kaplan Meier to make the splits using log-rank test, or fit a proportional parametric hazard with exponential distribution, and has a different way of splitting it?

Can I ask for help in unpacking this?

1. what are the `poisson` methods that `rpart.exp` uses?
2. what are "shrink" and "method" in `rpart.exp`'s `params`?
3. Quantiles of the survival function- I believe this requires modelling of the distribution of survival times. Is this happening here?

Or where can I get more information?

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `vignette('longintro', package = 'rpart')`. See e.g. chapter 8 for more info on the Poisson model.